# How to add another IF condition into formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel formula and am trying to add another `IF` condition. I need to add:

```
IF B3>B2 Then Return 1
```

I need the new `IF` statement nested in the formula below.

```
=IF($A$1>3,I1,$B$1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Google `nested If`

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Do you want the new `IF` statement nested *inside* the current one, or vice versa?  What should happen if the new `IF` returns `false`?

Comment: Freginold, yes. Nested inside the formula!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to visualize nested `IF` statements if you break them up. This is what you currently have:

```
=IF(
    $A$1>3,I1,$B$1
)
```

From your question, I'm guessing you want to nest the new `IF` statement so that it returns `1` if True, and executes the current `IF` statement if False.  (Correct me if that's wrong.) To do that, you would change your formula to look like this:

```
=IF(
    B3>B2,1,IF(
        $A$1>3,I1,$B$1
    )
)
```

If `B3>B2` then 1 will be returned; else your original `IF` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF($A$1>3,I1,IF(B3>B2,1,$B$1))
```

This reads as:

```
If $A$1 > 3 Then
    I1
Else
    If B3 > B2 Then
        1
    Else
        $B$1
    End If
End If
```